# MVC 4 Validation using Data Annotations and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I would like to validate a list of Names both server side and client side(JQuery).
In my *cshtml* file I am looping through the list names.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model. KeyConsultantList.Count; i++)  // 3 Rows
{
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model. KeyConsultantList [i].Name, new { @class = "textvalid" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model. KeyConsultantList [i].Name)</td>
         </tr>        
}
```

I would like to validate that only the first name in the list IsRequired. If a put an attribute: `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Name field is required")]` in the 
ModelList property this will validate all three fields. Please note that this is an example. In reality there will be 30+rows with the same field name. Therefore a loop is required.

```
public class ModelKeyConsultants
{
        public List<ModelList> KeyConsultantList {get;set;}


        public ModelKeyConsultants()
        {            

            KeyConsultantList = new List<ModelList>()
            {
               new ModelList(),
               new ModelList(),
               new ModelList()
            };
        }


        public class ModelList
        {           
            public string ContactName { get; set; }            
        }       
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to validate the first record in your collection?

Comment: Kinda confused on what you mean, but I notice you are not creating new `SingleKeyConsultant` in the declaration of your `KeyConsultantList`. All three items point to the exact same object in memory. I'm sure this is not what you intended. You should be doing `new ModelList()` since each consultant is going to be unique.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Yes that is correct. I would like to validate only the first record in the collection. The remaining records are not compulsory.